# Output grep results to text file, need cleaner output

Tags: text, grep, output

When using the Grep command to find a search string in a set of files, how do I dump the results to a text file?

Also is there a switch for the Grep command that provides cleaner results for better readability, such as a line feed between each entry or a way to justify file names and search results?

For instance, a away to change...

```
./file/path: first result
./another/file/path: second result
./a/third/file/path/here: third result
```

to

```
./file/path: first result

./another/file/path: second result

./a/third/file/path/here: third result
```

Comment: I love that these actual super helpful "not a real question" questions have ended up being in the top search results in Google years later.

Answer (score 155):

```
grep -n "YOUR SEARCH STRING" * > output-file
```

The `-n` will print the line number and the `>` will redirect grep-results to the output-file.

If you want to "clean" the results you can filter them using pipe `|` for example:
`grep -n "test" * | grep -v "mytest" > output-file`
will match all the lines that have the string "test" except the lines that match the string "mytest" (that's the switch `-v`) - and will redirect the result to an output file.

A few good grep-tips can be found [in this post](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/15-practical-unix-grep-command-examples/)

Comment: Does grep write only when it finishes or does it write line by line as it processes the content? Thanks!

Comment: @alfasin - isn't the single '>' going to overwrite the results in the output file? Shouldn't we use double '>>' in order to append the results into to the file?

Comment: @GTodorov yes, if you want to append use `>>`

Comment: For future visitors the answer to @Crista23's question is it writes when the grep has finished

Comment: `env | grep WSL >> test.txt`

Answer (score 46):

Redirection of program output is performed by the shell.

```
grep ... > output.txt
```

`grep` has no mechanism for adding blank lines between each match, but does provide options such as context around the matched line and colorization of the match itself. See the `grep(1)` man page for details, specifically the `-C` and `--color` options.

Answer (score 6):

To add a blank line between lines of text in `grep` output to make it easier to read, pipe (`|`) it through `sed`:

```
grep text-to-search-for file-to-grep | sed G
```